# 4x4 Fixed point matrix multiplication doesn't work

Tags: matrix, fixed, point, multiplication

I have this function which concatenates two matrices:

```
out->_11 = MAT_MUL(b->_11, a->_11) + MAT_MUL(b->_21, a->_12) + MAT_MUL(b->_31, a->_13) + MAT_MUL(b->_41, a->_14);
out->_12 = MAT_MUL(b->_12, a->_11) + MAT_MUL(b->_22, a->_12) + MAT_MUL(b->_32, a->_13) + MAT_MUL(b->_42, a->_14);
out->_13 = MAT_MUL(b->_13, a->_11) + MAT_MUL(b->_23, a->_12) + MAT_MUL(b->_33, a->_13) + MAT_MUL(b->_43, a->_14);
out->_14 = MAT_MUL(b->_14, a->_11) + MAT_MUL(b->_24, a->_12) + MAT_MUL(b->_34, a->_13) + MAT_MUL(b->_44, a->_14);
out->_21 = MAT_MUL(b->_11, a->_21) + MAT_MUL(b->_21, a->_22) + MAT_MUL(b->_31, a->_23) + MAT_MUL(b->_41, a->_24);
out->_22 = MAT_MUL(b->_12, a->_21) + MAT_MUL(b->_22, a->_22) + MAT_MUL(b->_32, a->_23) + MAT_MUL(b->_42, a->_24);
out->_23 = MAT_MUL(b->_13, a->_21) + MAT_MUL(b->_23, a->_22) + MAT_MUL(b->_33, a->_23) + MAT_MUL(b->_43, a->_24);
out->_24 = MAT_MUL(b->_14, a->_21) + MAT_MUL(b->_24, a->_22) + MAT_MUL(b->_34, a->_23) + MAT_MUL(b->_44, a->_24);
out->_31 = MAT_MUL(b->_11, a->_31) + MAT_MUL(b->_21, a->_32) + MAT_MUL(b->_31, a->_33) + MAT_MUL(b->_41, a->_34);
out->_32 = MAT_MUL(b->_12, a->_31) + MAT_MUL(b->_22, a->_32) + MAT_MUL(b->_32, a->_33) + MAT_MUL(b->_42, a->_34);
out->_33 = MAT_MUL(b->_13, a->_31) + MAT_MUL(b->_23, a->_32) + MAT_MUL(b->_33, a->_33) + MAT_MUL(b->_43, a->_34);
out->_34 = MAT_MUL(b->_14, a->_31) + MAT_MUL(b->_24, a->_32) + MAT_MUL(b->_34, a->_33) + MAT_MUL(b->_44, a->_34);
out->_41 = MAT_MUL(b->_11, a->_41) + MAT_MUL(b->_21, a->_42) + MAT_MUL(b->_31, a->_43) + MAT_MUL(b->_41, a->_44);
out->_42 = MAT_MUL(b->_12, a->_41) + MAT_MUL(b->_22, a->_42) + MAT_MUL(b->_32, a->_43) + MAT_MUL(b->_42, a->_44);
out->_43 = MAT_MUL(b->_13, a->_41) + MAT_MUL(b->_23, a->_42) + MAT_MUL(b->_33, a->_43) + MAT_MUL(b->_43, a->_44);
out->_44 = MAT_MUL(b->_14, a->_41) + MAT_MUL(b->_24, a->_42) + MAT_MUL(b->_34, a->_43) + MAT_MUL(b->_44, a->_44);
```

MAT_MUL looks like this:

```
#define MAT_MUL(o1,o2) ((GLfixed)((long)(o1)*(long)(o2))>>16)
```

The odd thing is that it doesn't work with fixed point values but with float values (MAT_MUL(o1,o2) (o1)*(o2) in this case). I traced the error down to this bit of code.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Maybe the multiplication is overflowing? Does the problem still happen if you change the macro to: #define MAT_MUL(o1,o2) ((GLfixed)(((int64_t)(o1)*(int64_t)(o2))>>16))

Comment: Not sure, but wouldn't that be a performance loss to first cast to 64 bit? Does that still be faster than using floats?

Comment: Converting to 64-bits shouldn't be very slow, especially on a 64-bit computer where it's just a load with sign extension. It's my understanding that converting ints to floats is a slow operation regardless of how fast floats are on their own.